# Distinguishing between equilibrium and non-equilibrium distributions?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory, non-equilibrium

Suppose a physical system is described by some effective double-well potential landscape with fluctuation-driven motion along this landscape. If we watch the system for a sufficiently long time and then count how much time was spent in each well, then the ratio of the two times $\frac{t_{1}}{t_{2}}$ should be equal to the ratio of the two potential minima $\frac{V_{2}}{V_{1}}$.

Pictorially, this is just because the time needed to get from one minimum to the other increases with increasing height of the energy barrier, which increases if the potential minimum is located further below.

Now suppose our observation time is so short that the system does not have time cross the barriers for sufficiently many times, such that counting the ratio of times spent in the two minima does not provide information about the ratio of the potential minima.

My confusion is about distinguishing between these two cases when we are given only the ratio of times. That is, if I give only the ratio of times, how do you know if that ratio is determined by the relative spacing of the potential minima or the position of the transition state ? Is it kinetically limited or thermodynamically limited ?